# Getting local master to track origin master

Tags: git, github, version-control

My git repo is in a bit of a weird place right now, so let me explain how I got here...

1. `cd /var`
2. `git clone https://github.com/..... www`
3. `cd www`
4. Realize I want to put the site in a sub-directory of www
5. `mkdir my-site`
6. `mv !(my-site) my-site`
7. `cd my-site`

Now when I run `git status`, it claims that **every single file** has been deleted, and that the `my-site` folder is not being tracked. Kind of makes sense: I moved **every single file**

To try and correct this I did the following:

1. `git init` -- create a new repo in "my-site"
2. `git remote add origin https://github.com/.....` -- make this repo a "clone" of my origin
3. `git fetch --all` -- make sure I'm aware of the most recent commits
4. `git branch -u origin/master master` -- tell my local master to track origin master

When I did this I got the following error:

```
fatal: branch 'master' does not exist
```

Running `git status` gives me the following:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ...

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Running `git branch -a` gives me:

```
remotes/origin/master
```

So I know I'm on a local master and I know a remote master exists, but I can't seem to tie the two together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no commits in the repo you initialised inside `my-site`, which is what's causing the hiccup in the `git branch -u origin/master master` command.  You could run `git reset origin/master` in `my-site`, after which `git branch -u origin/master` will set the upstream as intended.

You could also blow away all contents of `www` and just clone the repository into `www/my-site`, which seems less fiddly!

Comment: Will `git reset` modify any files, or just update the reflog?

Comment: `git reset` without options is equivalent to `git reset --mixed`, which does not modify the working tree.  See [the git-reset documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) for information on the other options.

Answer (score 1):

may be a bit long winded, but :

```
git checkout -b temp-branch
git branch -D master
```

You may want to commit files to temp-branch here or stash them

```
git checkout origin/master --track
git merge temp-branch
```

General house keeping (not necessary)

```
git branch -D temp-branch
```

It's a bit hacky, but should do the job